# angularJS get current element in html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui

I would like to do something like this in angularJS:

```
<div ng-class="{ 'hover-accordion': angular.element(this).children().length >= 3 }">
    <div ng-if="showA">...</div>
    <div ng-if="showB">...</div>
    <div ng-if="showC">...</div>
    <div ng-if="showD">...</div>
    <div ng-if="showE">...</div>
</div>
```

This means that if the parent div has more then 3 childs, I want the class 'hover-accordion'.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Mostly templates display a model (data from server). Use this model to alter the view. I wouldn't rely on the underlying DOM to manipulate the view. Sure you can but this wouldn't be the angular way.
So instead of checking the length of children of a dom element, check the length of the model data that is rendered by the view.

Here is a working plunker of what I mean: http://plnkr.co/edit/SzuAO1BTapelQYI6WFJa?p=preview

Comment: The ng-repeat used, is only for the demo. I had to guess what you try to accomplish and I thought you wanted some kind of accordion. Maybe if you provide more details on what you want to do, I could help you more.

Comment: I don't have an array that holds all the data.

Comment: how do you get the data from the server? Or is the template static?

Answer (score -1):

The children are made by PHP (or other server side code) ? Calculate and add the class with PHP.
But if children are made with angular model, juste use the length of the model.

Right ?

Comment: I am using AngularJS templates without server side rendering. This is single page application! Which length?? of which model??